# javafx connection to mysql

Tags: mysql, connection, javafx

we are building javafx application which will be presenting information about stocks. 
Here is the website:
http://analiza.host-ed.me/

But we've got a huge problem. Every free hosting doesn't allow remote mysql connection. And there is my question. When our site is on the server (which i linked) is this remote connection or local connection? 
When we put this javafx app as a site it can't connect like it was on the local machine...
Is there any solution? Thanks for help.
(we need to use free hosting, because it's only a school project..)

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Voting to close on that account, however to be constructive... I suppose the scope of your project has just expanded. Now you need to figure out how to set up a personal server or be satisfied in running the demo from your local machine.

Comment: So... when it is possible to access mysql from php code, why can't I do it from javafx? Or maybe can I..?

Comment: They are not allowing a connection to mysql from outside the server. I just thought you needed such a connection and that it was an implementation/configuration/service provider choice issue. After jewelsea answered I realized that you could configure mysql to accept remote requests but you are giving the clients a lot of power that way, security is tricky. What you generally want is web services (json, xml, possibly web sockets). Since you are using Java for front end development possibly using Java for the server side might make sense, consider Struts2/Spring-MVC?

Comment: The answer is: If you're running your app on a server and want to connect to the database on that same server it is a local connection using localhost!

Comment: It's a JavaFX app, it runs on a client, not a server markus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access MySQL from JavaFX. But JavaFX runs on a client and something like php usually runs on a server.  You will need a connection from your java app to MySQL.  As your hosting provider won't allow you to directly connect to the database port from your Java Client App, you will need some other way to connect.

You could tunnel through port 80, you could run a servlet (or php server code, etc) to intercept incoming traffic and proxy database calls through a HTTP based REST interface or you could install the DB locally on the client.

I'm going to assume, for a school project, it's ok for each client machine to have it's own database. In which case, instead of using MySQL, use a lightweight Java database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), bundle it with your app by including it's jar as a dependent library, [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm) the app plus DB jar as a signed WebStart application using the JavaFX packaging tools and host the files generated by the packaging tools at your hosting provider.

**Update**

Here is a sample application which uses a local H2 database on the client computer.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class H2app extends Application {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(H2app.class.getName());
  private static final String[] SAMPLE_NAME_DATA = { "John", "Jill", "Jack", "Jerry" };

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final ListView<String> nameView = new ListView();

    final Button fetchNames = new Button("Fetch names from the database");
    fetchNames.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        fetchNamesFromDatabaseToListView(nameView);
      }
    });

    final Button clearNameList = new Button("Clear the name list");
    clearNameList.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        nameView.getItems().clear();
      }
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 15;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(
      HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).children(
        fetchNames, 
        clearNameList    
      ).build(),      
      nameView
    );
    layout.setPrefHeight(200);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  private void fetchNamesFromDatabaseToListView(ListView listView) {
    try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
      if (!schemaExists(con)) {
        createSchema(con);
        populateDatabase(con);
      }
      listView.setItems(fetchNames(con));
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  private Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    logger.info("Getting a database connection");
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
  }

  private void createSchema(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    logger.info("Creating schema");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String table = "create table employee(id integer, name varchar(64))";
    st.executeUpdate(table);
    logger.info("Created schema");
  }

  private void populateDatabase(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    logger.info("Populating database");      
    Statement st = con.createStatement();      
    int i = 1;
    for (String name: SAMPLE_NAME_DATA) {
      st.executeUpdate("insert into employee values(i,'" + name + "')");
      i++;
    }
    logger.info("Populated database");
  }

  private boolean schemaExists(Connection con) {
    logger.info("Checking for Schema existence");      
    try {
      Statement st = con.createStatement();      
      st.executeQuery("select count(*) from employee");
      logger.info("Schema exists");      
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      logger.info("Existing DB not found will create a new one");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  private ObservableList<String> fetchNames(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    logger.info("Fetching names from database");
    ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Statement st = con.createStatement();      
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from employee");
    while (rs.next()) {
      names.add(rs.getString("name"));
    }

    logger.info("Found " + names.size() + " names");

    return names;
  }
}
```

There is a [corresponding NetBeans project](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app.zip) for this sample which will generate a deployable application.  The project can be tested in [webstart](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app/webstart.html) and [applet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app/applet.html) mode.

For the sample, the database is stored on the user's computer (not the server from which the application was downloaded) and persists between application runs.

The exact location depends on the jdbc connection initialization string.  In the case of my sample the database goes in the user's directory `jdbc:h2:~/test`, which is OS and User specific.  In the case of me for Windows it ends up at `C:\Users\john_smith\test.h2.db`.  Using a jdbc connection string such as `jdbc:h2:~/test` is preferable to a string such as `jdbc:h2:C:\\Baza` because a string with `C:\\` in it is platform specific and won't work well on non-windows systems.  For further information on h2 jdbc connection strings refer to the [connections settings in the h2 manual](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases).

The h2 system works such that if the database file already exists, it is reused, otherwise a new database file is created.  If you modify the database, shut the application down, then load the application again a week later, it is able to read the data created the week before.

Comment: thank you very much. but... "bundle it with your app by including it's jar as a dependent library" I am not sure what do you mean. I dowloaded h2-1.3.169.jar then added it to the build path in NetBeans. But when I put my app on the serwer it doesn't work - Java Runtime Error all the time. When I execute jar locally it works fine. why?

Comment: Don't know why it does not work for you - it works for me.  I created a [sample project](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app.zip), which can create a [web start application](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app/webstart.html) or [browser embedded application](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/h2app/applet.html). (I'll just host the links from this comment for a short while, then eventually take them down and delete this comment).

Comment: that's weird. Today it's working fine even on server...(I didn't change anything) thank you. When I use H2 database where exactly is the data stored? Locally on user computer? And if the user closes my program will th data stay on the hard drive? For example: Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:h2:EMPLOYEEDB", "sa", ""); It creates EMPLOYEEDB in my project folder. But when I put in on the server as a embedded application should it be: jdbc:h2:C:\\Baza  ?What does it mean: jdbc:h2:~/test ?

Comment: Glad that you got it to run.  I updated my answer to answer your additional questions.