# Pro n cons of using JavaFx with sqlite, or better option

Tags: user-interface, sqlite, javafx-2, javafx

I am creating a desktop application in JavaFx. 
1.I want to save all data on client machine (data should be so big). 
2.Want simple configuration with database (user friendly).
3.I search sqlite is better option for those type of application but i don't get it the advantages.So please tell me the pro n cons.
4.Is there any option for sqlite for such a application?
I am fresher with JavaFx . So I want a help .

Answer (score 3):

While sql-lite is likely fine and is [usable from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite), as you are writing a Java application, I think a pure java database might be preferable - for example [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

To use H2, just include the H2 jar file on your application's class path and there is no additional setup required for use.  Here is an example of using a [H2 database from JavaFX over JDBC](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4955598).

The H2 based example JavaFX application is from [javafx connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433829/javafx-connection-to-mysql) and the answer there may provide some more basic info to get you started.

Once you start using a standard api like jdbc or jpa and have established a database connection, the great majority of database related code is pretty agnostic of the backend database system chosen.

As to canvasing detailed opinions of pros and cons of one particular database over another - a google search is probably a better resource for that than a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I have a big database in my project .So H2 database is helpful or not?

Comment: It's probably fine.  If the standard H2 [faq](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html) and [performance documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html) is insufficient for you, you can prototype your solution to determine limitations or ask a new StackOverflow question with the [h2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/h2) tag, providing specific details of what big means and how the database is intended to be used.